# Store results of Storyline 2 quiz in google sheet then email me the latest result

Tags: google-apps-script

Please excuse my compete newness. I am not a coder.

What I need is to store results of quizes taken in some elearning I have made in a google spreadsheet and to email me everytime the sheet gets a new entry ie everytime someone completes the quiz.

From the e-learning heros forum at Articulate i have a code which will perform the task of taking variables from the storyline quiz and writing them to a google sheet.

I also have a bit of code which will gather information from the last row of the sheet and email them to me.

If i test the script in the google editor it sends me the email. It will not send me the email when the sheet is updated by someone completing the quiz. The google sheet does get filled in everytime someone finished the quiz just no email. Here is the code:

```
var SHEET_NAME = "DATA";
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();


function doGet(e) {
  return handleResponse(e);

}

function doPost(e) {
  return handleResponse(e);


}

function handleResponse(e) {



  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {

    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("MmzGq0lh9jQjkO-_i8STL2nsLKXLh7K_NHzR8yD5gnk"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; // get next row
    var row = [];

    for (i in headers) {
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp") { // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
        "result": "success",
        "row": nextRow
      }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch (e) {

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
        "result": "error",
        "error": e
      }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();



    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, lastRow, 10);
    var values = range.getValues();
    var date = values[0][0]
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+08:00", "dd/MM/yyyy   H:mm a");
    var firstname = values[0][2]
    var surname = values[0][1]
    var score = values[0][3]
    var result = values[0][5]
    var emailAddress = "My email"
    var message = "Name:\t" + firstname + " " + surname + "\n\nDate:\t\t" + formattedDate + "\nScore:\t\t" + score + "%\nStatus:\t" + result;
    var subject = "Training " + result;

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

  }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have tried some more testing and the the error is:

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, since you say you're a beginner.. Did you change the email variable with your own email address?

```
var emailAddress = "My email"
```